# Besides BFS and DFS, what is another algorithm that can be used to determine bipartiteness?

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science, graph-theory, bipartite

I know we can use BFS and DFS to determine if a graph is bipartite or not. For a research paper, I need to talk about a third algorithm as well. Any answers? Much appreciated!

Comment: Pick any P-complete problem, reduce.

Comment: [Blossom's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

You can read this https://www.quora.com/How-does-Edmonds-Blossom-algorithm-work.
You can read details about the algorithm in this pdf : [Edmonds-Blossom-algorithm](http://matthewkusner.com/MatthewKusner_BlossomAlgorithmReport.pdf)